# Go field name or path of a struct field pointer?

Tags: go, reflection

I know it would not be very idiomatic but I would like to know if it is possible to get the field name of a pointer using reflection assuming it is known that the pointer references a struct field (maybe even having the struct value in question). For example

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

type Example struct {
    Foo int
    Bar string
}

func GetFieldName(originStruct any, fieldPtr any) string { ... }

func main() {
    v := Example{ 42, "baz" }
    f := &(v.Foo)

    fmt.Println(GetFieldName(v, f))
    // Prints "Foo"
}
```

A more advanced version of this would recursively get the path of the field even if along the way there are structs or slices and return a full path to the nested field pointer.

For example `GetFieldPath(v, &(v.Foos[3].Bar)) -> []any{"Foos", 3, "Bar"}` or something similar.

**Why would I ever need this?** — I am building a small experimental frontend framework all in golang and I need this to implement double binding in a clean way (without passing strings around)

Comment: `f` is a pointer to a string, it contains no other information about the structure of the program, nor does the string value itself.

Comment: The Go runtime internally probably has some way of doing this (I believe the GC handles pointers to internal members by keeping the whole object alive), but there doesn't seem to be any available interface for what you're asking.

Comment: You can do this by comparing the addresses of the struct's fields against the field pointer, _but only_ if you also pass a pointer to the struct `v` rather than a shallow copy of it, which is what you're doing above. However, for the advanced version, keep in mind that not all expressions are addressable, for example if `Foos` in `v.Foos[3].Bar` is a `map[int]struct` (rather than a slice) then `&v.Foos[3].Bar` is illegal since map values are not addressable and inferring the path to `Bar` is not possible.

Comment: https://go.dev/play/p/qXoo48nNqiR

Comment: Ah thanks I didn't know map values were not addressable in Go